# Text Find replace using Wildcard or regex

Tags: regex, visual-studio, text, wildcard

I am trying to replace some text using Regular Expression (using Visual Studio)
For instance

I have to replace **Canada 123 567-890**  to **Canada 123-567-890** 
I mean to add a `-` in the gap after the 123

Using Wildcard find replace, I try:

```
Find: Canada ****567-890
Replace: Canada 123-567-890
```

This works fine. But how can I generalize it? For instance how can I do it for any number instead of 123 (see below)

```
Canada 454 767-785
Canada 899 567-788
Canada 345 345-645
Canada 788 456-766
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
(^Canada\s+\d\d\d)\s(.*)
```

Then replace with:

```
\1-\2
```

[See it work](http://regex101.com/r/kC9aD0)

Another is to use a positive lookahead so that you can correctly handle overlapping matches:

```
(\d\d\d)\s(?=\d\d\d)
```

Then replacement is

```
\1-
```

[See that work](http://regex101.com/r/nJ7mF5)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following.

```
Find: ^(Canada\s+\d{3})\s
Replace: \1-
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"Canada\ [0-9][0-9][0-9]\ [0-9][0-9][0-9]\-[0-9][0-9][0-9]"
```

or

```
"Canada\ [0-9]{3}\ [0-9]{3}\-[0-9]{3}"
```

Something like this should work to parse or return the string. You will have to replace the first space with your - character.

Once you have found your text from your input stream then you replace it using
low tech methods. You are trying to replace the second space which get complicated using Regular expressions.

```
int lastIndexPos = foundStr.LastIndexOf(' ');
Result = FoundStr.Substring(0,lastIndexPos) + "-" + FoundStr.Substring(lastIndexPos+1);
```

Something low tech like this should work.

Comment: The find works (means "Canada\ [0-9][0-9][0-9]\ [0-9][0-9][0-9]\-[0-9][0-9][0-9]")         But what should be the GENERAL Replace expression?

Comment: @SebThomas Expanded my answer a little

Comment: That finds it, but doesn't give a general REPLACE expression, which other answers have done.

Comment: I am not out to dazzle people. Just get a working solution. The poser of this question can cheery pick what they need from all the answers. Often a clever solution is a pain to patch six months later when you ave forgotten what you were doing or worst you take over someone else's code. @ClickRick I don't see your answer!

Comment: I don't know why you people are making things that much complicated. Pl see my answer.

Comment: You are correct. If his data is simple in the format he is describing.

Answer (score 0):

Use NotePad++

Find: **'Canada (\d+) '**

Replace: **'Canada $1-'**
(single quotes are not needed)

That is it!

Comment: The question said that you were using Visual Studio. It also said about wanting a more general solution. On that basis, I'd say that hwnd and dawg had the best answers.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not familiar with VS, however the regexp for that in general is `/^(\w+) (\d+) (\d+-\d+)$/g`

An example in Javascript :

```
'Canada 123 567-890'.replace(/^(\w+) (\d+) (\d+-\d+)$/g, '$1 $2-$3');
"Canada 123-567-890"
```

I *think* in VS you have to change `$1 $2-$3` to `\1 \2-\3`.